# Processing apache2.deb error "trying to overwrite /var/www/html" which is also in package nginx-common

Tags: apt, apache-httpd, nginx

Any time I try to run `sudo apt install <package>` I get the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.9) but 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.10 is to be installed
           Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.9) but 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.10 is to be installed
           Depends: apache2-utils (= 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.9)
 lollypop : Depends: python3-pylast but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I get the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 228 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/95.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 425435 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.10) over (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/var/www/html', which is also in package nginx-common 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Edit**: And when I try to remove nginx or nginx-common I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.9) but 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.10 is to be installed
           Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.9) but 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.10 is to be installed
           Depends: apache2-utils (= 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.9)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried running `sudo apt install apache2 nginx-common-` but I get the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-mail : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-stream : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 nginx-core : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So then I tried `sudo apt install apache2 nginx-common- libnginx-mod-http-image-filter- libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter- libnginx-mod-mail- libnginx-mod-stream- nginx-core-` and got the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-core (< 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (< 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: nginx-core (>= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (>= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (>= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (>= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried removing nginx and also disabling it but it doesn't seem to work, I don't really need nginx so removing it is fine, does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that trying to remove `nginx` while `apache2` is in an inconsistent state isn’t going to get anywhere.

Instead, remove `apache2`:

```
apt remove apache2
```

and then purge all `nginx`-related packages:

```
apt purge --autoremove '*nginx*'
```

Once that’s done,

```
apt install apache2
```

should work.